# GROUP BY A, B, C, and else for counting data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to try group by with data with certain types and etc.

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.T_TEST(
       TYPE nchar(1) NOT NULL,
       Qty int NOT NULL
 )

 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('A','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('A','1');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('A','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('B','22');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('B','21');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('C','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('C','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('C','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('C','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('D','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('D','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('D','2');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('E','1');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('E','1');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('E','4');
 INSERT INTO [T_TEST] VALUES ('F','5');
```

The result I am wondering is like this.

```
TYPE   Count
A       3
B       2
C       4
etc     7
```

I could do with get total count and subtract count A,B,C.
But I believe it's not a good logic, Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following and see working fiddle:

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('A','B','C') THEN TYPE ELSE 'etc' END as [Type],
     COUNT(Type) as [Count]
FROM
    T_TEST
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('A','B','C') THEN TYPE ELSE 'etc' END
GO
```

```
Type | Count
:--- | ----:
A    |     3
B    |     2
C    |     4
etc  |     7
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8cc275ee75ea0eb7f70ad7cd94c41791)*

Answer (score 1):

You need a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```sql
SELECT TYPE, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.T_TEST
GROUP BY TYPE
ORDER BY TYPE;
```